# How to show alert Box after picking an image using react-native-image-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new in React-native Here I want to Show an alert box after choosing an image from gallary, like Are you sure you want to choose this Image ? there will be two option yes and cancel. if i press yes it will upload that image in server and show alert image uploaded successfully or console log response and if press no then it will return back to the screen choose an image. Here is my code what should i add for getting this result?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  Switch,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class VisitingCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: false,
      enable: true,
    };
  }

  isEnable() {
    this.setState({
      enable: !this.state.enable,
    });
  }

  Header() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.visitingCardTextContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <AntDesign name="arrowleft" color="#ffffff" size={30} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.visitingCardText}>Visiting Card</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.isEnable()}>
            {this.state.enable ? (
              <Image source={require('./assets/edit_disable.png')} />
            ) : (
              <Image source={require('./assets/edit_enable.png')} />
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.isEnable()}>
            {this.state.enable ? (
              <Image
                style={styles.shareImg}
                source={require('./assets/share.png')}
              />
            ) : (
              <Image
                style={styles.shareImg}
                source={require('./assets/share.png')}
              />
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }


  selectImage() {
    let options = {
      title: 'You can choose one image',
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
      },
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log({response});

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
        Alert.alert('You did not select any image');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        let source = {uri: response.uri};
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#edf7ff'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 0.9}}>
          {this.Header()}
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignContent: 'stretch'}}>
            <View style={styles.themeContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.lightText}>Light Mode</Text>
              <Switch
                style={{marginLeft: 10}}
                trackColor={{false: 'gray', true: 'teal'}}
                thumbColor="white"
                ios_backgroundColor="gray"
                onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({toggle: value})}
                value={this.state.toggle}
              />
              <Text style={styles.darkText}>Dark Mode</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.uploadImageContainer}>
              <Image source={require('./assets/camera.png')} />
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectImage}>
                <Text style={styles.uploadImageText}>Upload Image</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.saveButtonContainer}>
          {this.state.enable ? (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.saveButton}>
              <Text style={styles.saveText}>Save</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ) : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
    height: SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - 400,
    backgroundColor: '#0066b3',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  visitingCardTextContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  visitingCardText: {
    fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: 22,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#ffffff',
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    flex: 0.2,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  shareImg: {
    marginLeft: 15,
  },
  themeContainer: {
    height: 70,
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 130,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  lightText: {
    fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeueCondensed',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: 18,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    color: '#434343',
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
  darkText: {
    fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeueCondensed',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: 18,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    color: '#434343',
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  uploadImageContainer: {
    height: 70,
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  uploadImageText: {
    fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeueCondensed',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: 18,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    color: '#434343',
    margin: 5,
  },
  saveButtonContainer: {
    flex: 0.1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  saveButton: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    height: 55,
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 80,
    backgroundColor: '#0066b3',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  saveText: {
    fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: 19,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Alert.alert('', 'Are you sure you want to choose this Image ?', [
 {
  text: "Cancel",
  onPress: () => null,
  style: "cancel"
 },
 {
  text: "YES",
  onPress: () => selectImage()
 }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log({response});

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
        Alert.alert('You did not select any image');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        let source = {uri: response.uri};
        // Show your alert here
        alert('Image selected successfully')
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const pickImage = async (submit) => {
    const permissionResult =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()
    if (!permissionResult.granted) return alert(MEDIA_PERMISSION)
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspectRatio: [4, 3],
    })
    if (result?.uri) {
        Alert.alert(
            WHAT_TO_UPLOAD,
            '',
            [
                { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {} },
                {
                    text: 'Yes, Continue',
                    onPress: async () =>
                        await submit({ name: 'image', ...result }),
                },
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
        )
    }
}
```